# Randomly generate a number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to randomly generate a number between 1 and 10 and also display it on a webpage, does anyone have any idea how i'd go about doing this?

preferably in full since i have no idea what im doing

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random numbers in Javascript in a specific range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+generate+random+number&rlz=1C1CHMO_enUS499US499&oq=javascript+gener&aqs=chrome.4.69i57j0l5.5458j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript+generate+random+number

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As you've probably guessed by now, asking questions like this is frowned upon because you appear to not have tried. I recommend you have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org - this is (imho) a great resource for using web technologies. Good luck!

Comment: "*i have no idea what im doing*," well there's your problem. Look, we've all been there before, but you need to do some research yourself before you ask a question on SO. At least show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 4):

C'mon man. Google something. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naomi/X3XaV/)

```
var min = 1, max = 10,
    num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

document.body.innerHTML = num;
```